# Excel Power Query: Passing parameter to oDataFeed URL throws error

Tags: odata, powerquery

When a direct number for the TestPlanID is given it works.
When passing the value from sheet to a Query and then appending it to URL throws an error.

```
Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator & to types Text and Number.
Details:
    Operator=&
    Left=https://analytics.dev.azure.com/OrgName/ProjName/_odata/v3.0-preview/TestPoints?$apply=filter((TestSuite/TestPlanId eq 
    Right=39128
```

[image: Power query error]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
eq"""&varTPID&"""
```

If value of `varTPID` is an integer/decimal, can you change the first line in `power query` to `varTPID=Text.From(varTestPlanID)` and then use `eq"""&varTPID&"""`

Also I think, `TestPoints?"&"$apply` needs to be changed to `TestPoints?$apply`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried but getting the same error.

Comment: $apply is in next line, that did not make a difference if I place it in one line or two lines

Comment: The problem is with the parameter value, its type, and in the query. Not sure how to handle it.

Comment: is the value of `varTPID` an integer?

Comment: Yes it's an integer value, could not use double quotes